# How can i get value of column based on values of two other columns in Oracle Using C#?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a table in Oracle which saves the percentage of tax based on different salaries, eg Tax is 5% if Salary is >5000 and Salary is < 10000.
Here is the structure of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE TaxDetailTable
   (    MinSalary FLOAT(126), 
    MaxSalary FLOAT(126), 
    TAX_PERCENT FLOAT(126)
   )
```

now i want to get that percentage value based on the salary i input using C#.
Right now i am just comparing the salary i have provided to the input values, but i want some efficient way to do this.Can someone help me?
My query is:

```
Select Tax_Percent From TaxDetailTable Where MinSal >= inputSal And MaxSal <= inputSal
```

Comment: Do you have some significant speed issue with this? Are the performance issue detectable with a single call? This query is simple and shouldn't take so long.  If you call it really often your performance issue is due to the ammount of query you do and not the query itself

Comment: Shouldn't MinSal be <= inputSal instead of >=? and vice versa for MaxSal?  Right now you query is likely to return no data unless MinSal is greater than MaxSal.  You could just use `where inputSal between MinSal and MaxSal`

Comment: what do you mean with "i want some efficient way to do this" ? cant image the query takes more than 2 ms since it should contain no more than 20 rows

Answer (score 2):

This is a better query and likely to return data:

```
Select tax_percent From taxDetailTable Where inputSal Between minSal And maxSal
```